# Monitoring reboot/shutdown execution with auditd

Tags: linux, operating-system, audit

I'm interested in monitoring reboot/shutdown command execution (and the user who executed such command) using auditd.

I've been testing the following rule:

```
-a exit,always -F arch=b64 -S execve -k  my_rule
```

when I execute whatever command, it generates syscall events:

```
$> ls
$> ausearch -k my_rule
time->Tue Mar 31 07:36:06 2020
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1585640166.203:1186): arch=c000003e syscall=59 success=yes exit=0 a0=97c1c0 a1=a0d080 a2=9f7de0 a3=7ffe54a5de60 items=2 ppid=11024 pid=11088 auid=1000 uid=1000 gid=1000 euid=1000 suid=1000 fsuid=1000 egid=1000 sgid=1000 fsgid=1000 tty=pts1 ses=4 comm="ls" exe="/usr/bin/ls" subj=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 key="my_rule"
```

But, if I execute the reboot command, it doesn't generate any event. I cannot find the cause of this or any solution.

Any help would be welcome, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to specify the exact executable

```
-a exit,always -F arch=b64 -S execve -F path=/sbin/reboot -k my_rule
-a exit,always -F arch=b64 -S execve -F path=/sbin/init -k my_rule
```